# How can i create sequence from other sequence in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sequence

How can i create sequence from other sequence in Oracle as `create table tablename as (select * from tablename)`.I tried like this `create sequence sequence_name as select sequence_name` but i got error.

Comment: you want this so you can have new seq start at the same number?  Why not just grab the DDL (either in your IDE or using dbms_metadata), change the sequence name, and run it?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
declare
v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
v_sql := dbms_metadata.get_ddl('SEQUENCE',YOUR_SEQUENCE_NAME_HERE);
dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
end;
```

Then copy output, change sequence name and execute;

Answer (score -1):

To copy a table's structure and data, omit the parens from your first statement: 
`create table newtable as select * from oldtable;`